# free wifi with web html login page - auto login?

Tags: scripts, login

A place where I visit very regularly had open access free wifi with no password on the wifi SSID

However, it's one of the ones where you can connect to the wifi, but when you try to go to a webpage, it first redirects you to a login page, where you have to put in the username and password.
The username and password very rarely change (i.e. it's not changed for at least a year).

Quite frequently my connection drops and I have to go through the logon process again, is there any way to automate this with a script in Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can perform this with the command **POST** :

```bsh
POST http://[ADRESS]:[PORT]/ <<< 'auth_user=ID&auth_pass=PASSWORD&accept=Continue'
```

Then you just have to copy this script in the folder `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`. When your connect to a network with NetworkManager, it will pass the interface used in `$1` and if this is a connect or disconnect in `$2` to your script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1 $2" = 'wlan0 up' ]
then
    essid=$(iwconfig wlan0 | grep -o 'ESSID:".*$' | sed 's/^ESSID:"\(.*\)".*$/\1/')
    case "$essid" in
        'Freewifi')
            POST http://[ADRESS]:[PORT]/ <<< 'auth_user=ID&auth_pass=PASSWORD&accept=Continue' ;;
        'Other')
            POST http://[ADRESS]:[PORT] <<< 'accept_cgu=1' ;;
    esac
fi
```

Be aware to fill all  required input in your form (sometimes there is security input and that can be really complicated to automate the connexion in a script).

That was a long time ago that I perform an script to perform this and I didn't test it.

Hope this answer help.